# Two "cin"s in a row won't work

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to write into a variable in two different set arguments using this code, but it's not allowing me to enter the value for the 2nd cin.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int T1,T2,T3,D,car_type;
double total;

cout<<"Please enter the values for T1 T2 T3 D: ";
cin>>T1,T2,T3,D;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Please Choose a Car where 1 = Honda, 2 = Toyota, 3 = Mercedes: ";
cin>>car_type;
if (car_type = 1)
{
    total = T1*D;
    cout<<"The cost of a full tank for a Honda is "<<total<<" Dirhams.."<<endl;
}/* else
if (car_type = 2)
{
    total = T2*D;
    cout<<"The cost of a full tank for a Toyota is "<<total<<" Dirhams.."<<endl;
} else
if (car_type = 3)
{
    total = T3*D;
    cout<<"The cost of a full tank for a Mercedes is "<<total<<" Dirhams.."<<endl;
} */
}
```

Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: i think you want to do `cin >> T1 >> T2` etc

Comment: First of all in the first usage of `cin` you can't use commas as separators. Use `>>`s.

Comment: There are a few beginner mistakes here. [Might I suggest a good book.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191)

Comment: Unrelated, but `car_type = 1` is an assignment, not a comparison. You want to use `==`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, the comma can be present in both declarations (variable declarations, parameter lists) and expressions. In expressions, it's an operator that evaluates the operands and returns the last one.

Basically

```
cin>>T1,T2,T3,D;
```

evaluates `T1,T2,T3` and `D` and then returns `D`, which means, in your particular case, it's equivalent to

```
cin>>D;
```

To correctly chain `operator>>` on `cin`, do:

```
cin >> T1 >> T2 >> T3 >> D;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>T1,T2,T3,D;
```

is not doing what you expext it to do. To understand that read @Luchian Grigore's answer. This is what your code should be

```
cin>>T1>>T2>>T3>>D;
```

To accept multiple values using `cin`, use the above code ( That is, separate the variables using `>>` and not using `,` ).

Also change

```
if (car_type = 1)
```

to

```
if (car_type == 1)
```

`=` is an assignment operator, in your code it assigns the value `1` to `car_type`. To check for equality use `==`.

Comment: Even if it compiles, It definitely does not do what it wants us to do.

Comment: Obviously, but why does it compile? (i.e. this would be a much better answer if it explained the actual behavior)